# Perl DBD::mysql chopping words out of longtext field

Tags: mysql, perl

I have a Wordpress MySQL database I'm trying to extract some data out of using perl's DBD::mysql.

If I do this at the command line:

```
mysql --raw mydb <<EOF

select post_content from wp_posts where ID = 195;
EOF
```

I get what I expect...here are the first two sentences:

```
I guess someone famous enough to have <a
href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hee_Il_Cho" target="_blank">his own
Wikipedia page</a> is worth anyone's consideration.  I'm not familiar
with AIMAA, but they appear to have quite a few affiliated school
(particularly in the UK).
```

But if I do this in perl:

```
$dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=$dbname";
$dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);

$sql_page_list = $dbh->prepare ("
  SELECT post_title, post_content
  FROM wp_posts
  WHERE post_status = 'publish'
  AND post_type = 'page'
  ORDER BY post_title
");
$sql_page_list->execute();
while ( $prog_row = $sql_page_list->fetchrow_hashref ) {
  print $prog_row->{post_content} . "\n";
...
```

I get:

```
I guess someone famous enough to have <a
href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hee_Il_Cho" target="_blank">his own
Wikipedia page</a>worth anyone's consideration.  not familiar with
AIMAA, but they appear to have quite a few affiliated school
(particularly in the UK).
```

Here is the same text with the missing words marked:

```
I guess someone famous enough to have <a
href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hee_Il_Cho" target="_blank">his own
Wikipedia page</a> **is** worth anyone's consideration.  **I'm** not
familiar with AIMAA, but they appear to have quite a few affiliated
school (particularly in the UK).
```

Any idea what might be causing that?  The post_content is longtext.  The table_collation is utf8_general_ci.

This pattern continues throughout the text - words missing.  It happens for all the posts.

Comment: The two queries you executed are different. I'm not saying that that is the issue, just that it makes troubleshooting easier if you use the exact same query for both.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there were some octal 240s embedded.  This garbled the output.  I did an od -c and saw them.

Removing them was easy:

```
$content =~ s/\xa0/ /g;
```